# jquery parent selector - Syntax error, unrecognized expression )

Tags: jquery, syntax, expression, selector, parent

If you run this code and click on some of the links you'll get this error message:

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: )

Also I found that maybe the ')' error is related to the selector of the *holder* element which is: "p.parent()"

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function () {
        var holder = $('p').wrap('<div class="holder"></div>').parent();

        $('a', holder).live('click', function () {
            console.log( $(this).text() );
            return false;
        });

        holder.append('<a href="#">append</a> <a href="#">some</a> <a href="#">elements</a>');
    });
</script>

<p>test</p>
```

I don't know where the error might be, I'm starting to think that it's a bug in jquery and the way it is using the selector with **live**. In other parts of may code I have selector like this $('a', holder).eq(..) and it works fine.

I just got it to work with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function () {
        var holder = $('p').wrap('<div class="holder"></div>').parent();

        /*$('a', holder).live('click', function () {
            console.log( $(this).text() );
            return false;
        });*/

        holder.on('click', 'a', function () {
            console.log( $(this).text() );
            return false;
        });

        holder.append('<a href="#">append</a> <a href="#">some</a> <a href="#">elements</a>');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: _Not_ the source of your error, but .live() is deprecated in favor of .delegate() or .on().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using on() instead of live() solves the error.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function () {
    var holder = $('p').wrap('<div class="holder"></div>').parent();

    /*$('a', holder).live('click', function () {
        console.log( $(this).text() );
        return false;
    });*/

    holder.on('click', 'a', function () {
        console.log( $(this).text() );
        return false;
    });

    holder.append('<a href="#">append</a> <a href="#">some</a> <a href="#">elements</a>');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

can't wrap a string around an element which is what you are doing with:

```
var holder = $('p').wrap('holder').parent();
```

Needs to be an html tag , or a jQuery object

```
var holder = $('p').wrap('<div>').parent();
```

See API for wrap()

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: The test code actually was:
<pre>$(function () {
   var holder = $('p').wrap('<div class="holder"></div>').parent();

   $('a', holder).live('click', function () {
    console.log( $(this).text() );
    return false;
   });

   holder.append('<a href="#">append</a> <a href="#">some</a> <a href="#">elements</a>');
  });</pre>

Comment: Whats wrong with the formatting ..? Anyways it doesn't work with actual element it was typo in my first post. The test is with `var holder = $('p').wrap('<div class="holder"></div>').parent();` and it gives the error message. I just got it to work with holder.on('click', 'a', function () {

Comment: put a demo together in jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KYTEx/ - here you are. Just open your console and hit the links.

Comment: Yes I know that it's working with $('.holder a') but I can't use it like this since my code is executed inside plugin body and must take the parent of each instance separately. I'll mark my answer. Thank you.

Comment: I can mark it as usefull because it is but it's not the answer and I already was modified my post with the on() function. I'm sorry that I've mislead you with my typo in first place.